# Old Japanese Sci-Fi Live Action, Swords took bullets?

Tags: movie, story-identification

I remember watching an old Japanese live action on the sci-fi channel, and the most memorable thing was that the swords took these bullets or energy pellets.  I think there was a war or an invasion of some kind.  Power Ranger-esque costumes and pretty good flick from what I can remember, maybe a female lead.

Comment: Star Wars??????

Comment: Power Rangers?????

Comment: Tokusatsu have many fan sites.  This sounds a lot like one of the very many incarnations of Kamen Rider, but I'm not an expert.

Comment: It was neither Star Wars or Power Rangers.  I looked up Kamen Riders and that wasn't it.  I think Power Rangers costume might have been a bit misleading.  The costumes were more along the lines of "The Guyver", harder lines.

Comment: It was Mirai Ninja.

Comment: @kneesus Post an answer giving a short summary of that movie and how it fits your question. Then accept that answer.

Answer (score 4):

Abandoned by OP, but film appears to be [**Mirai Ninja**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirai_Ninja_(film)) (Cyber Ninja) from 1988. The protagonist Shiranui, a cybernetic ninja, is on a mission to rescue a kidnapped princess. The film is set in a futuristic world where humans & cyborgs are at war with each other.

While attempting to rescue the princess, Shiranui finds himself being forced to fight both sides, and the cyborgs do indeed load energy pellets into their arms and fire them, as seen in the [trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j1FohqSH3SE).

[image]